# Socket port not opening in Docker Swarm Cluster (Root Cause Identified)

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, apache-karaf

I have following setup

- Two VMs
- created overlay network
- created two docker swarm services

  docker service create --name karaf1-service --replicas 1 --network karaf_net karaf1:2.0.0

  docker service create --name karaf2-service --replicas 1 --network karaf_net karaf2:2.0.0

Now these containers open socket port at start, i observed some time it successfully able to create it lot of time it fails.

```
ServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(serverPort)
```

if both containers get start on one node its mostly successfull, but when containers get created on different node it almost fails every time.

before troubleshooting for network issue, container atleast should create sockets.

this container not able to open socket

```
root@bd48643080b2:/opt/apache/apache-karaf-4.1.5# netstat -tulnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8101            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      61/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1099          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      61/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41551           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      61/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:44853        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44444           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      61/java
```

Following container able to create it on port 4550, but some times it vice versa

```
root@38d26c7dde1a:/opt/apache/apache-karaf-4.1.5# netstat -tulnp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:37347           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      61/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8101            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      61/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4550            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      61/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:37575        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1099          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      61/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:35321         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      61/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44444           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      61/java
```

***Root Cause Identified:***
As i am creating two services so while creating first service i provide second service as hostname to first service to keep verifying status so java throwing error on hostname like "karaf2-service"

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: karaf2-service: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
```

Now i cant add entry of karaf2-service in etc/hosts so socket dont complain as i dont know which IP would be assign to docker-swarm service? in overlay network we mostly communicate with service names.

Any suggestions to resolve this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, is to check on container startup if you can reach the other service, and if not, wait a few seconds then try again.

There are multiple tools to do this, such as wait-for-it: https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it